# git-svn: automatically importing/creating svn revisions as git tags

Tags: tags, automation, git-svn

I am using git-svn to work with a svn repository. The git `master` branch is mirroring the svn `trunk` branch (the only svn branch in use), i.e. there is a one to one relation between elements on the master branch and the trunk branch.

I want to have git tags that corresponds to svn revisions, so that I can do things like for instance `git diff r123 workbranch` to see what I have done compared to svn revision 123.

The revisions are not tagged when I do `git svn rebase`, so I have created the following script that I run post svn rebase:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

open(PIPE, "git log master |");
# Format for the pipe output:
# ...
# commit 6b24b8fdc6a25d35b01140dc1ac054697133423d
# ...
#      git-svn-id: https://server.example.com/svn/project/trunk@594 164096ca-3471-41d1-a9ce-9541462a8c31
# ...
my $commit = "";
my $i = 0;
foreach my $line (<PIPE>) {
    if ($line =~ /^commit ([\da-f]+)/) {
        $commit = $1;
        next;
    }
    next unless $line =~ /^\s+git-svn-id: .*\/trunk\@(\d+) /;
    my $git_svn_id = $1;
    run("git", "tag", "-f", "r$git_svn_id", $commit);
    last if $i++ == 20;
}
close(PIPE);

sub run {
    print join(' ', @_), "\n";
    return system(@_);
}
```

This script gets the job done, but I have to run it manually every time, and I have (arbitrarily) capped it at checking the last 21 revisions so there is a theoretical risk of missing some (but I will see that from the printing).

The question: Is there any way I can automate this so that I just run `git svn rebase` and all imported revisions will be tagged in git? Any [hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) I can use?

PS
Yes, I am aware of svn find-rev, but I want in absolutely no way having to write commands as complicated as `git diff $(git svn find-rev r123) $(git svn find-rev r124)` instead of just `git diff r123 r124`.

Comment: Why so difficult? If you don't like write complicated commands, you could create an alias.

Comment: - Doctor, my arm hurts when I do this. - Well don't do that then!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a crazy idea:  Trap `bash` commands and automatically replace any `r1234` strings with SHA hashes:

```
shopt -s extdebug

enhance_rev_parse () {
    [ -n "$COMP_LINE" ] && return  # do nothing if completing
    case "$BASH_COMMAND" in
    *r[0-9]*)
        eval $(echo "$BASH_COMMAND" | sed -e 's/r[0-9][0-9]*/$(git svn find-rev &)/g')
        return 1
        ;;
    esac
}

trap 'enhance_rev_parse' DEBUG
```

Comment: This actually sort of works, but it is a bit to hack-ish and "leaks" too much. `git tag -d r123` will not work for instance. And I cannot use `git tag -l` to get a list since they not proper tags.

Comment: I even forgot to put `git` into the `case` pattern after testing, so it even affects other commands!

Answer (score 0):

#### Short Answer and Caveats

There is not a way to hook the `git svn rebase` command that I'm aware of (or `git svn dcommit`).

What you *can* do is use the `post-rebase` hook.  However, this is only invoked when the history is actually updated by the rebase -- if you run `git svn rebase` and there's no new SVN commits that affect the current Git branch, no changes will take effect.

#### Ensure You Used `--stdlayout`

With regard to creating Git tags for SVN tags in a single command, if you did not originally clone the repository with...

`git svn clone --stdlayout`

I would recommend that you re-clone the repository.  This will make your life much easier.

#### Telling Git About *New* SVN Tags

To tell Git about new SVN tags and branches, use the command `git svn fetch --all`.  The command `git svn rebase --fetch-all` also performs this action.

#### Automatically `git tag` all SVN tags

In order to convert thse newly-fetched SVN tags into Git tags, one way is to just walk the the references.

```
#!/bin/sh
git svn fetch --all &&
git for-each-ref refs/remotes/origin/tags |
while read ref
do
  tagName=$(echo $ref | cut --delimiter / --fields=5)
  git tag -f "$tagName" "refs/remotes/origin/tags/$ref"
done
```

Put this file as `.git/hooks/post-rebase`.

Comment: I could not find any reference to a post-rebase hook in neither the documentation (http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks, http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html), nor in the latest git source code. Have you extended git in some other way?

Comment: Also note that I am looking for importing svn revisions, not svn tags.